# Смена контекста callback без его явного изменения

Tags: javascript

Я всегда думал, что контекст метода меняется только тогда, когда его явно подменяем при помощи методов call или apply. Но сейчас на деле я узнал, что меняется он всегда. Это так или у меня что-то сломалось?
Для примера: если взять callback и передать его в другой объект, то при вызове callback() меняется и его контекст.

И если это так и должно быть, то единственным и верным решением так и остается биндинг в конструкторе?

**Дополнение:**

```
function EventDispatcher(target){
    this.target = target;
}

EventDispatcher.prototype = {
    callback: undefined,
    addEventListener: function(callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    },
    dispatchEvent: function(args){
        this.callback(args);
    },
    toString: function(){
        return '[object EventDispatcher]';
    }
};

function Two(){
    EventDispatcher.call(this, this);
}

Two.prototype = Object.create(EventDispatcher.prototype);
Two.prototype.constructor = Two;

Two.prototype.toString = function(){
    return '[object Two]';
}

function Three(two){
    this.two = two;
    this.two.addEventListener(this.handler);

}

Three.prototype.toString = function(){
    return '[object Three]';
}

Three.prototype.handler = function(args){
    console.log('[object Three] => handler', args, this.toString());
}

var two = new Two();
var three = new Three(two);

two.dispatchEvent('good'); // [object Three] => handler good [object Two]
// как видно, обработчик находится в контексте [object Two]
// и как теперь передать свойства из события я не знаю, так как this уже не то...
```

[**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6p6jv2p/)

Comment: Это?
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aL9mr6d9/

Comment: Я вообще вижу ваше неудобство, только не могу понять, как вы к нему пришли. Мне как-то не приходилось всерьез делать bind на всё подряд. Мало того, следует помнить, что если вы так сделаете, то не получится в будущем делать call и apply, чем лично я пользуюсь куда чаще, чем bind.

Comment: Хм, так вы явно указали контекст two здесь:

    this.two.addEventListener(this.handler);

Что тут ещё ожидать.

А ещё вы вызвали из two addEventListener с хэндлером из Three, т.е. объект two в результате изменился.

Посмотрите [вот этот проект](http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/) может, подсмотрите что-то интересное по вашей теме.

Comment: Потому что вы вызвали addEventListener объекта two, у него this - two.


     otherObject.object.method()
                   /|\
                    |____this в method

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/w3s22m6t/

Другими словами, если раскрыть скобки, то вы написали

    two.callback=three.handler

Такая запись вам понятна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно указали контекст  two для метода addEventListener() здесь:

```
 this.two.addEventListener(this.handler);
```

Что тут ещё ожидать.

А ещё вы вызвали из two addEventListener с хэндлером из Three, т.е. объект two в результате изменился, потому что вы вызвали addEventListener объекта two, у него this - two.

```
 otherObject.object.method()
               /|\
                |____this в method
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/w3s22m6t/

Другими словами, если раскрыть скобки, то вы написали

```
two.callback=three.handler
```

Такая запись вам понятна?

Comment: @vas, что вы понимаете под изменением объекта? Я под этим словом понимаю изменение его свойств. У вас свойство callback поменялось в two, потому что в конструктор Three вы передали ссылку на two.

Comment: Код

    <-четыре пробела, так-же как  и в ответах/вопросах

По поводу two.addEventListener() :) Просто на самом деле оно должно быть three.addEventListener() , т.е. вы должны наследовать метод. Надо придумать, как объяснить... скажем, на примере некого socket, вы делаете

    var socket=new Socket(req);

значит вызов события должен быть у socket, а обработчик - какой угодно:

    socket.addEventListener(handler)

тогда у handler будет this===socket, и это правильно.

Comment: Ну, вы проект посмотрите, он же чуть ли не порт этих сигналов. А хотел сказать вот ещё что: если вы называете методы как-то обще, то лучше чтобы они и вели себя в соответствии с какой-то спецификацией, чем вас, кстати, не устроило http://nodejs.org/api/events.html ?

Comment: Смотрел, и там тоже контекст передают иначе, все то же самое.  
Свой диспетчер переделал http://jsfiddle.net/n3eauLva/1/ , а делал я его, потому что не подумал о нодевском. Сейчас нодевский попробую.